# Can some please let me know how to install the jboss-as-7.1.0.Final in windows 64 bit

Tags: jboss

Can some please let me know how to install the jboss Final in windows 64 bit when i am trying to run standalone.bat file it is coming on within few seconds it go off i have already set the env path please some one do the needfuul

Answer (score 0):

As you have already set ENV variables. I am assuming you have set `JAVA_HOME` and `JBOSS_HOME`.

- Open command prompt
- Goto {JBOSS_HOME}\bin folder and run standalone.bat

Then you can see error on screen. Paste error here if getting issue.

Comment: compile:
compile-jsps:
Building jar: C:\Users\1284\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JBoos\dist\JBoos.war
Starting JBoss Application Server
JBoss Application Server Started
Distributing C:\Users\1284\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JBoos\dist\JBoos.war to [org.jboss.as.ee.deployment.spi.DeploymentManagerTarget@49158173]
Deploying C:\Users\1284\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JBoos\dist\JBoos.war
Failed
JBAS016154: Operation start started
JBAS016153: Operation start failed on target: org.jboss.as.ee.deployment.spi.DeploymentManagerTarget@49158173

Comment: its getting failed while i am running the project